# Sorting CSV in pandas with respect to column (string)

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Am sorting a csv wrt one column but now this string is getting complicated and am not sure how to sort this

Why am still stick with pandas is like i have write back the sorted values back to csv

```
CSV
Snapshot,Status
21.001.1154_2019-01-04_14-37-47_1280868,Released
21.001.1183_2019-01-04_16-37-47_1280868,Unit Tested
21.001.1183_2019-01-04_14-37-47_1280868,Release

I used:
dd.sort_values(['Snapshot'],ascending=True)
du.to_csv(unit_file,header =True,index=False)

dataframe:
C:\Users\320047585\Sathish\Python>python sample.py
Before Sort
                              Snapshot       Status
0  21.001.1154_2019-01-04_14-37-47_1280868     Released
1  21.001.1183_2019-01-04_16-37-47_1280868  Unit Tested
2  21.001.1183_2019-01-04_14-37-47_1280868      Release
```

And that returned sorted values,before first _but now if both the ids are same i need to check date and even date is same i need to sort on time,any insights would be great help

```
Expected output
21.001.1154_2019-01-04_14-37-47_1280868,Released
21.001.1183_2019-01-04_14-37-47_1280868,Released
21.001.1183_2019-01-04_16-37-47_1280868,Unit Tested
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need string split with reindex, check below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`s.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to get the *to_be_sorted* value folloed by [`df.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df_new=df.reindex(df.Snapshot.str.split("_").str[2].sort_values().index)
print(df_new)

                                  Snapshot       Status
0  21.001.1154_2019-01-04_14-37-47_1280868     Released
2  21.001.1183_2019-01-04_14-37-47_1280868     Released
1  21.001.1183_2019-01-04_16-37-47_1280868  Unit Tested
```

If you need to take the date and time both into consideration use:

```
data_new = data.join(data.Snapshot.str.split("_",expand=True)).sort_values(by=[0,1,2])
print(data_new)

                                 Snapshot       Status           1         2  \
0  21.001.1154_2019-01-04_14-37-47_1280868     Released  2019-01-04  14-37-47   
2  21.001.1183_2019-01-04_14-37-47_1280868     Released  2019-01-04  14-37-47   
1  21.001.1183_2019-01-04_16-37-47_1280868  Unit Tested  2019-01-04  16-37-47   

         3  
0  1280868  
2  1280868  
1  1280868
```

Of course then you can remove the unwanted columns.

Comment: @Sathishkumar Pleasure, I could help. Please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer if it helped you. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the whole string has to be sorted i added a minor change to anky's answer

```
Before
df_new = df.join(df.Snapshot.str.split("_",expand=True).drop(0,1)).sort_values(by=[1,2])

After
data_new = data.join(data.Snapshot.str.split("_",expand=True)).sort_values(by=[0,1,2])
```

it considers the whole string

More Interestingly

```
data.sort_values(['Snapshot'],ascending=True) 
Also doing the perfect sorting..! it ignores underscores and dots
```